# How to access associated changeset during the tfs build

Tags: git, tfs, build, continuous-integration, devops

I'm new to the TFS, trying to setup build and release pipeline for DB Deployment. Would like to access associated changesets (changed files) for the build in the TFS pipeline.

Associated Changesets is coming up in the build log once the build is done. I would like to access it during the build run in the pipeline. So I could pull out the report (release notes) out of it.

Couldn't find any pre-defined variables for my requirement. Any suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the build changes (changesets or commits) during the build we TFS Rest API.

The API is:

```
https://tfs-server:8080/tfs/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/changes?api-version=5.0
```

In the results you get a JSON with the changesets/commits details (even if the build not finished).

So during the build pipeline add a PowerShell task which get the API results, something like:

```
$currentBuildId = $env:Build_BuildId
$url = "https://tfs-server:8080/tfs/{collection}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/$currentBuildId/changes?api-version=5.0"
$results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType application/json -UseDefaultCredntials
```

Comment: Thank you, Am using TFS Version 16.131.27701.1
But when i hit the url in my browser, its redirecting me to the Sign in page. Is there anything am missing ?

Comment: And getting an error from the TFS pipeline,
Invoke-RestMethod : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 

Process completed with exit code 0 and had 1 error(s) written to the error stream.

******************************************************************************

Comment: I fixed the url to TFS (it was to azure devps so you got the sign in page). can you check now? (replace "tfs-server" with your TFS url)